# Array sorting in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

Hi i have a 289x2 array that i want to sort in MatLab. I want to sort the first column into numerical ascending order. However I want to keep the second column entry that is associated with it. Best way to explain is through an example.

```
x = 76  1 
    36  2 
    45  3
```

Now I want to sort x so that it returns an array that looks like:

```
x = 36  2
    45  3
    76  1
```

So the first column has been sorted into numerical order but has retained its second column value. So far I have tried `sort(x,1)`. This sorts the first column as i want but does not keep the pairing. This returns x as:

```
x = 36  1
    45  2
    76  3
```

Any help would be great. Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what [**`sortrows`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) does.

```
x=sortrows(x);    % or x=sortrows(x,1);
```

or if you want to use [**`sort`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) then get the sorted indexes first and then arrange the rows accordingly like this:

```
[~, idx] = sort(x); %Finding the sorted indexes
x = x(idx(:,1),:) ; %Arranging according to the indexes of the first column
```

---

**Output for both approaches:**

```
x =
   36     2
   45     3
   76     1
```